# Error installing Open Source Redis server on ec2

Tags: redis

I am installing Open Source Redis server on `ec2`. 
I have successfully connected to `ec2` using my pem. I have downloaded `Redis`.
Issued the following commands:

```
tar xvzf redis-stable.tar.gz > cd redis-stable.
```

The next step: make && make install is not working.

I am getting the following error:

> ~/redis-stable$ make && make install The program 'make' can be found
>   in the following packages:  * make  * make-guile  Try: sudo apt
>   install  ubuntu@ip-xxx.xx.xx.xx:~/redis-stable$

What is the need to continue with this installation process? I need to complete this installation/build process. I tried the `sudo` command as well, that is getting an error.

Comment: To compile Redis from its C source code, you need compiler tools such as the the 'make' program, linker, etc. You will also need the development libraries and headers for all dependencies of Redis.

Comment: please edit your post and add the error generated by `sudo apt install make` (assuming you do want to build redis instead of using a precompiled version)

Answer (score 1):

Any specific reason why you would want to compile and install redis? If not, you can simply execute below.

`sudo apt-get install redis-server`

Answer (score 0):

Give the following command to install the required Dependencies

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

After that you can continue the installation with

```
make && make install
```

Comment: error : Hint: It's a good idea to run 'make test' ;)

make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/redis-stable/src'
cd src && make install
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/ubuntu/redis-stable/src'
    CC Makefile.dep
Hint: It's a good idea to run 'make test' ;)
    INSTALL install
install: cannot create regular file '/usr/local/bin/redis-server': Permission denied
Makefile:286: recipe for target 'install' failed
make[1]: *** [install] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/redis-stable/src'
Makefile:9: recipe for target 'install' failed
make: *** [install] Error 2

Comment: Use 'sudo' before make and make install

Comment: sudo make && sudo make install